# java class without any method, but contains logic under static keyword

Tags: java

I have few questions about the below code snippet:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public static String TEMP_DIR;
    public static List<String> LEvents;
    ......//some more public static members......

   static{
      //logic to fill all the members of this class
    }
}
```

1. I am wondering when will the logic which fills the members be executed?
2. And is this approach different if i would have used actual static method to execute the logic and call it once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
static {
    //logic to fill all the members of this class
}
```

code is known as a [static initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7).

> I am wondering when will the logic which fills the members be executed?

The Java Language Specification says

> A static initializer declared in a class is executed when the [class is initialized (§12.4.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1).

You then ask

> And is this approach different if i would have used actual static
>   method to execute the logic and call it once?

With a static initializer, the JVM takes care of executing the code. With a `static` method, you would have to call it yourself. For it to be equivalent, you would probably also want to guarantee that the method is only called/executed once.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the static block will execute once and only once when the class is loaded by the ClassLoader. The ClassLoader will load it once a statement executes that refers to the class.

If you wrote a static method and called it once then it would have the same effect **but** you'd have to worry about concurrent access to the method, and you'd need to ensure manually that the method was only executed once.